# Debug in Android Studio cannot continue between breakpoint

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

I was doing my normal android development. But after changing branch and forth, suddenly when I tried to debug my app the debug "control" panel is gone, so I cannot continue the debug process once stumbled on a breakpoint. I didn't change anything in the debug settings, android studio settings, or even the gradle etc.

I have tried changing the debugger settings into (java + native) but it only change the debug process name from Java Only into Java + Native without showing the debugger control panel.

I am using android hedgehog for a while now.

Please help, thank you

[image]

[image]